# Check number of invocations within class in case of JUnit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I have a code which calculates something, caches is, and if already calculated, then reads from the cache; similar to this:

```
public class LengthWithCache {
    private java.util.Map<String, Integer> lengthPlusOneCache = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public int getLenghtPlusOne(String string) {
        Integer cachedStringLenghtPlusOne = lengthPlusOneCache.get(string);
        if (cachedStringLenghtPlusOne != null) {
            return cachedStringLenghtPlusOne;
        }
        int stringLenghtPlusOne = determineLengthPlusOne(string);
        lengthPlusOneCache.put(string, new Integer(stringLenghtPlusOne));
        return stringLenghtPlusOne;
    }

    protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
        return string.length() + 1;
    }
}
```

I want to test if function `determineLengthPlusOne` has been called adequate number of times, like this:

```
public class LengthWithCacheTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetLenghtPlusOne() {
        LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache();

        assertEquals(6, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple"));
        // here check that determineLengthPlusOne has been called once

        assertEquals(6, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple"));
        // here check that determineLengthPlusOne has not been called
    }
}
```

Mocking class `LengthWithCache` does not seem a good option, as I want to test their functions. (According to my understanding we mock the classes used by the tested class, and not the tested class itself.) Which is the most elegant solution for this?

My first idea was to create another class `LengthPlusOneDeterminer` containing function `determineLengthPlusOne`, add pass it to function `getLenghtPlusOne` as parameter, and mock `LengthPlusOneDeterminer` in case of unit testing, but that seems a bit strange, as it has unnecessary impact on the working code (the real clients of class `LengthWithCache`).

Basically I am using Mockito, but whatever mock framework (or other solution) is welcome! Thank you!

Comment: I think that testing this with an isolated unit test with mocking is not the best idea. Instead, write a test that only verifies the *externally observable behavior* of the class under test. The internal use of caching is, in the end, just an implementation detail meant to improve performance. Maybe a test can be written to detect such performance improvement (using `System.nanoTime()`); if not, then maybe the caching is worthless and could be removed.

Comment: Thanks four your comment. Caching mechanism turned to be useful in practice.

Comment: Why a downvote for this question ? Objectively, it's a very interesting subject mixing design and unit testing. It deserves better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like using mocks is overthinking it.  The *LengthWithCache* can be overridden as an anonymous-inner class within the context of a test to get the invocation count.  This requires no restructuring of the existing class being tested.

```
public class LengthWithCacheTest {
    @Test
    public void verifyLengthEval() {
        LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache();
        assertEquals(6, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple"));
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyInvocationCounts() {
        final AtomicInteger plusOneInvkCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache() {
            @Override
            protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
                plusOneInvkCounter.incrementAndGet();
                return super.determineLengthPlusOne(string);
            }
        };

           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());

           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");

           assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
    }
}
```

> It's worth noting the separation between the two tests.  One verifies
>   that the length eval is right, the other verifies the invocation
>   count.

---

If a wider data set for validation is required, then you can turn the Test above into a *Parameterized* test and provide multiple data sets and expectations.  In the sample below I've added a data set of 50 strings (lengths 1-50), an empty string, and a null value.
**Null fails**

```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class) 
    public class LengthWithCacheTest  {
        @Parameters(name="{0}")
        public static Collection<Object[]> buildTests() {
            Collection<Object[]> paramRefs = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            paramRefs.add(new Object[]{null, 0});
            paramRefs.add(new Object[]{"", 1});
            for (int counter = 1 ; counter < 50; counter++) {
                String data = "";
                for (int index = 0 ; index < counter ; index++){
                    data += "a";
                }
                paramRefs.add(new Object[]{data, counter+1});
            }

            return paramRefs;
        }

        private String stringToTest;
        private int expectedLength;

        public LengthWithCacheTest(String string, int length) {
            this.stringToTest = string;
            this.expectedLength = length;
        }



    @Test
    public void verifyLengthEval() {
        LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache();
        assertEquals(expectedLength, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(stringToTest));
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyInvocationCounts() {
        final AtomicInteger plusOneInvkCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache() {
            @Override
            protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
                plusOneInvkCounter.incrementAndGet();
                return super.determineLengthPlusOne(string);
            }
        };

           assertEquals(0, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(stringToTest);
           assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(stringToTest);
           assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
           lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(stringToTest);
           assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());

    }
}
```

Parameterized testing is one of the best ways to vary your data set through a test, but it adds complexity to the test and can be difficult to maintain.  It's useful to know about, but not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks; this approach is similar to the one provided by davidhxxx, but much simpler.

Comment: This method is simpler because it doesn't handle side effects. It assumes that always the same String value is used. A complete unit test must check side effects and not only simple and easy scenarios. Because the problem comes often from tricky scenarios.
I will edit my answer to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant way would be to create a separate class that does the caching and decorate with it the current class (after removal of the caching), this way you can safely unit test the caching itself without interfering with functionalities of the base class.

```
public class Length {
    public int getLenghtPlusOne(String string) {
        int stringLenghtPlusOne = determineLengthPlusOne(string);
        lengthPlusOneCache.put(string, new Integer(stringLenghtPlusOne));
        return stringLenghtPlusOne;
    }

    protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
        return string.length() + 1;
    }
}

public class CachedLength extends Length {
    private java.util.Map<String, Integer> lengthPlusOneCache = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public CachedLength(Length length) {
        this.length = length; 
    }

    public int getLenghtPlusOne(String string) {
        Integer cachedStringLenghtPlusOne = lengthPlusOneCache.get(string);
        if (cachedStringLenghtPlusOne != null) {
            return cachedStringLenghtPlusOne;
        }
        return length.getLenghtPlusOne(string);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily test the caching my injecting a mocked `Length`:

```
Length length = Mockito.mock(Length.class);
CachedLength cached = new CachedLength(length);
....
Mockito.verify(length, Mockito.times(5)).getLenghtPlusOne(Mockito.anyInt());
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal! Indeed that is not a syntactically fully correct solution, but the approach is good.
I think it is not necessary to inherit from Length, but use it an an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need mock to address your need. 
To test the internal behavior (is `getLenghtPlusOne()` was called or not called), you would need to have a method to access to the cache in LengthWithCache.
But at level of your design, we imagine that you don't want to open the cache in a public method. Which is normal.
Multiple solutions exist to do a test on the cache behavior despite this constraint.
I will present my way of doing. Maybe, there is better.
But I think that in most of cases, you will be forced to use some tricks or to complexify your design to do your unit test.

It relies on augmenting your class to test by extending it in order to add the needed information and behavior for your test.
And it's this subclass you will use in your unit test.
 
The most important point in this class extension is not to break or modify the behavior of the object to test. 
**It must add new information and add new behavior and not modify information and  behavior of the original class otherwise the test loses its value since it doesn't test any longer the behavior in the original class.**

The key points :
-   having a private field `lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall`which registers for the current call if the method `lengthPlusOneWasCalled`was called

-   having a public method to know the value of `lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall` for the string used as parameter. It enable the assertion.

- having a public method to clean the state of `lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall`. It enable to keep a clean state after the assertion.

```
package cache;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LengthWithCacheTest {

    private class LengthWithCacheAugmentedForTest extends LengthWithCache {

        private Set<String> lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall = new HashSet<>();

        @Override
        protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
            // start : info for testing
            this.lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall.add(string);
            // end : info for testing
            return super.determineLengthPlusOne(string);
        }

        // method for assertion
        public boolean isLengthPlusOneCalled(String string) {
            return lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall.contains(string);
        }

        // method added for clean the state of current calls
        public void cleanCurrentCalls() {
            lengthPlusOneWasCalledForCurrentCall.clear();
        }

    }

    @Test   
   public void testGetLenghtPlusOne() {
    LengthWithCacheAugmentedForTest lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCacheAugmentedForTest();

      final String string = "apple";
      // here check that determineLengthPlusOne has been called once
      Assert.assertEquals(6, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(string));
      Assert.assertTrue(lengthWithCache.isLengthPlusOneCalled(string));

      // clean call registered
      lengthWithCache.cleanCurrentCalls();

      // here check that determineLengthPlusOne has not been called
      Assert.assertEquals(6, lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne(string));
      Assert.assertFalse(lengthWithCache.isLengthPlusOneCalled(string));
    }                    
}
```

**Edit 28-07-16 to show why more code is needed to handle more scenarios**

Suppose, i will improve the test by asserting that there is no side effects : adding an element in the cache for a key has not effect on how the cache is handled for other keys.
This test fails because it doesn't rely on the string key. So, it always increments.

```
@Test
    public void verifyInvocationCountsWithDifferentElementsAdded() {
     final AtomicInteger plusOneInvkCounter = new AtomicInteger();
     LengthWithCache lengthWithCache = new LengthWithCache() {
         @Override
         protected int determineLengthPlusOne(String string) {
           plusOneInvkCounter.incrementAndGet();
          return super.determineLengthPlusOne(string);
          }
      };

     Assert.assertEquals(0, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
     lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
     Assert.assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
     lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("pie");
     Assert.assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());
     lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("eggs");
     Assert.assertEquals(1, plusOneInvkCounter.get());        
  }
```

My version is longer because it provides more features and so, it can handle a broader range of unit testing scenarios .

**Edit 28-07-16 to point the Integer caching**

No direct relation with the original question but little wink :)
Your `getLenghtPlusOne(String string)` should use `Integer.valueOf(int)` instead of `new Integer(int)`
`Integer.valueOf(int)` uses in internal a cache

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I also considered that (in another case I used similar approach) but my basic problem with this is the unit tests very heavily rely on the very details of internals of the class to be tested. Whatever small modification on the base class should be reflected in the related unit test classes immediately, therefore it makes hard to refurbish the base class. This is a working solution, but I think it is not really elegant.

Comment: You are welcome. I love unit testing. It's longer but for good reasons. Read my edit and my comment on the  answer of Jeremiah.

Answer (score 1):

As this was an interesting question, I decided to write the tests. In two different ways, one with mocking and the other without. (Personally, I prefer the version without mocking.) In either case, the original class is tested, with no modifications:

```
package example;

import mockit.*;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LengthWithCacheMockedTest {
    @Tested(availableDuringSetup = true) @Mocked LengthWithCache lengthWithCache;

    @Before
    public void recordComputedLengthPlusOneWhileFixingTheNumberOfAllowedInvocations() {
        new Expectations() {{
            lengthWithCache.determineLengthPlusOne(anyString); result = 6; times = 1;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void getLenghtPlusOneNotFromCacheWhenCalledTheFirstTime() {
        int length = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");

        assertEquals(6, length);
    }

    @Test
    public void getLenghtPlusOneFromCacheWhenCalledAfterFirstTime() {
        int length1 = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
        int length2 = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");

        assertEquals(6, length1);
        assertEquals(length1, length2);
    }
}
```

---

```
package example;

import mockit.*;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LengthWithCacheNotMockedTest {
    @Tested LengthWithCache lengthWithCache;

    @Test
    public void getLenghtPlusOneNotFromCacheWhenCalledTheFirstTime() {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis(); // millisecond precision is enough here
        int length = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
        long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;

        assertEquals(6, length);
        assertTrue(dt >= 100); // assume at least 100 millis to compute the expensive value
    }

    @Test
    public void getLenghtPlusOneFromCacheWhenCalledAfterFirstTime() {
        // First time: takes some time to compute.
        int length1 = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");

        // Second time: gets from cache, takes no time.
        long t0 = System.nanoTime(); // max precision here
        int length2 = lengthWithCache.getLenghtPlusOne("apple");
        long dt = System.nanoTime() - t0;

        assertEquals(6, length1);
        assertEquals(length1, length2);
        assertTrue(dt < 1000000); // 1000000 nanos = 1 millis
    }
}
```

Just one detail: for the tests above to work, I added the following line inside the `LengthWithCache#determineLengthPlusOne(String)` method, in order to simulate the real-world scenario where the computation takes some time:

```
try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided code; checking the time passed is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the proposal by krzyk here is my fully working solution:

The calculator itself:

```
public class LengthPlusOneCalculator {
    public int calculateLengthPlusOne(String string) {
        return string.length() + 1;
    }
}
```

The separate caching mechanism:

```
public class LengthPlusOneCache {
    private LengthPlusOneCalculator lengthPlusOneCalculator;
    private java.util.Map<String, Integer> lengthPlusOneCache = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public LengthPlusOneCache(LengthPlusOneCalculator lengthPlusOneCalculator) {
        this.lengthPlusOneCalculator = lengthPlusOneCalculator;
    }

    public int calculateLenghtPlusOne(String string) {
        Integer cachedStringLenghtPlusOne = lengthPlusOneCache.get(string);
        if (cachedStringLenghtPlusOne != null) {
            return cachedStringLenghtPlusOne;
        }
        int stringLenghtPlusOne = lengthPlusOneCalculator.calculateLengthPlusOne(string);
        lengthPlusOneCache.put(string, new Integer(stringLenghtPlusOne));
        return stringLenghtPlusOne;
    }

}
```

The unit test for checking the `LengthPlusOneCalculator`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LengthPlusOneCalculatorTest {
    @Test
    public void testCalculateLengthPlusOne() {
        LengthPlusOneCalculator lengthPlusOneCalculator = new LengthPlusOneCalculator();
        assertEquals(6, lengthPlusOneCalculator.calculateLengthPlusOne("apple"));
    }

}
```

And finally, the unit test for `LengthPlusOneCache`, checking the number of invocations:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LengthPlusOneCacheTest {
    @Test
    public void testNumberOfInvocations() {
        LengthPlusOneCalculator lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock = mock(LengthPlusOneCalculator.class);
        when(lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock.calculateLengthPlusOne("apple")).thenReturn(6);
        LengthPlusOneCache lengthPlusOneCache = new LengthPlusOneCache(lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock);

        verify(lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock, times(0)).calculateLengthPlusOne("apple"); // verify that not called yet
        assertEquals(6, lengthPlusOneCache.calculateLenghtPlusOne("apple"));
        verify(lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock, times(1)).calculateLengthPlusOne("apple"); // verify that already called once
        assertEquals(6, lengthPlusOneCache.calculateLenghtPlusOne("apple"));
        verify(lengthPlusOneCalculatorMock, times(1)).calculateLengthPlusOne("apple"); // verify that not called again
    }
}
```

We can safely do the mocking mechanism, as we are already convinced that the mocked class works properly, using its own unit tests.

Normally this is built into a build system; this example can be complied and run from command line as follows (files `junit-4.10.jar` and `mockito-all-1.9.5.jar` have to be copied to the working directory):

```
javac -cp .;junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.5.jar *.java
java -cp .;junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LengthPlusOneCalculatorTest
java -cp .;junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.5.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LengthPlusOneCacheTest
```

However, I'm still not fully satisfied with this approach. My issues are the following:

1. Function `calculateLengthPlusOne` is mocked. I would prefer such a solution where a mocking or whatever framework just calculates the number of invocations, but the original code runs. (Somehow mentioned by davidhxxx, however I do not find also that a perfect one.)
2. The code became a bit over-complicated. This is not the way one would create normally. Therefore this approach is not adequate if the original code is not of our fully control. This could be a constraint in reality.
3. Normally I would make function `calculateLengthPlusOne` static. This approach does not work in such a case. (But maybe my Mockito knowledge is weak.)

If some could address any of these issues, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The JMockit mocking library is able to satisfy all of issues 1, 2 and 3 above. That said, personally I still get the feeling this is something best tested without any mocking. It would be useful to know what the actual real-world caching is being used for, as the example shown here is too contrived.

Comment: Yes, it seems so; the solution by Jeremiah is really a simple but great one. Indeed, I leave here my solution, at least because of the syntax.

Comment: The real world example is calculating the distance between two fully qualified names of source code elements, as described in article https://dibt.unimol.it/staff/fpalomba/documents/C8.pdf. It is very frequent and surprisingly slow. In the practice there are a few hundred source code elements; for example let's say 300. I create a 300x300 array, and save the already calculated distance value. Next time I just need to read out the already saved value.

Comment: "Normally I would make function calculateLengthPlusOne static"
I am not a fan of static method. JMockit, PowerMock and other "special" unit test apis allow to mock static methods. But from my personal experience, it's a non sense when you master you design. Because static methods prevents from using the OOP power  and a flexible way to code (polymorphyim,  passing the object as parameter, tricky unit tests...).
I reserve a static methods for "technical", "raw" tasks I don't need to mock. For example, a conversion, a mapping, a logging, etc... Not for logic.

Comment: davidxxx, that's a good idea how to decide if a function, which could be made static, should it really be made or not.